# Успеваемость и посещаемость студента

Tags: delphi, база-данных

Моё задание сделать программу по которой человек может просмотреть успеваемость и посещаемость студента. БД делал в Access, подключал через ADOQuery (через него всё делать и надо). Также использую DBGrid. В первом DBGrid'е у меня показывает специальности колледжа, во втором группы колледжа. И проблема в том что я не знаю как сделать связь между ними! Чтоб при нажатии на специальность во втором DBGrid'е автоматически показывало группы данной специальности (после надо будет сделать подобную связь группа - студенты группы и студенты - посещаемость/успеваемость). Знаю как это сделать в ADOTable, но его использовать нельзя, надо использовать ADOQuery.
Я использовал вот такой код

```
procedure TForm3.DBGrid1CellClick(Column: TColumn);
begin
  with form2.ADOQuery2 do
  begin
    Close;
    SQL.Clear;
    SQL.Add('select * from groups where spec = "' + ADOQuery1.FieldByName('spec').AsString + '"');
    Open;
  end;
end;
```

но компилятор постоянно ругается! То ему не нравится ковычки, то `ADOQuery` или `ADOQuery1.FieldByName` и `AsString`...
Буду благодарен если поможете!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для связи master-detail не нужно писать обработчики DBGrid1CellClick и тому подобные. Достаточно один раз настроить связь.

```
Q1.sql.text := 'select id, name from groups';
Q2.DataSource := DS1;
Q2.sql.text := 'select id, fio from students where group_id = :id';
```

Связь устанавливается через DataSource и параметры в запросе. Имена параметров в детальном запросе подставляются по имени поля в главном запросе, т.е. в главном было поле id, значит в подчиненном будет доступен параметр :id.

Эту связь можно установить как из кода (см. выше), так и в object inspector'е вообще без написания кода.

По поводу написания запросов. Никогда не пытайтесь подставить какие-либо значения (кроме integer может быть) прямым изменением текста запроса. Всегда используйте параметры. Ваши данные могут и сломают вашу программу в зависимости от ввода.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Вы меня просто спасли!)

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы на ковычки не ругался попробуйте quotedstr:

```
'select* from groups where spec='+quotedstr(ADOQuery1.FieldByName('spec').AsString)
```

Answer (score 0):

Я раньше работал тоже в делфи. Там надо использовать одиночные кавычки. Попробуй следующее выражение:

```
 'select * from groups where spec='+#39+ADOQuery1.FieldByName('spec').AsString+#39
```

Comment: У меня и в первом и во втором случае пишет ошибку, компилятору не нравится ADOQuery1.FieldByName и AsString